# Proving a set is open in $X$ given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a non-empty subset $A$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ a non-empty subset of it. Show that the set $$U= \{x\in X \vert d(x,A) >0 \}$$ is open in $X$.

Let $x \in U$ and $r = d(x,A)$. Define $\varepsilon = \frac{r}{2}$.

Construct a ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$, if we can show that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subset U$ we're done right?

Pick any $z \in B(x, \varepsilon)$, this implies that $d(x,z) < \varepsilon = \frac{r}{2} \Rightarrow 2(d(x,z)) < r.$

But we had that $r = d(x,A)$ so we get that $$2(d(x,z)) < d(x,A) \leqslant d(x,z)+d(z,A)$$

so overall we have $$2(d(x,z)) < d(x,z) +d(z,A) \Rightarrow d(x,z) < d(z,A).$$

How should I continue from here? This doesn't immediately imply that $z \in U$ right?

Comment: Another method you could try would be to show that the complement $X\setminus U$ is (sequentially) closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z\in B(x,\epsilon)$ and $y\in A$. Then $r=d(x,A)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, so $d(z,y)\ge r-d(x,z)>\epsilon$. Since $y$ was an arbitrary element of $A$, $d(z,A)\ge\epsilon>0$, and $z\in U$.

In fact $U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$, since $\operatorname{cl}A=\{x\in X:d(x,A)=0\}$.

Comment: I tried to visualize this, but cannot seem to understand the inequality $r=d(x,A)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. These three don't seem to form a "triangle"? It seems that there are four points here if we consider $A$ as a "point" also?

Comment: @Nate: By definition $d(x,A)\le d(x,y)$ for every $y\in A$, so in full it’s $$r\le d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in U$. Then we claim that $B\Big(x,\frac{d(x,A)}{2}\Big)$ is contained in $U$, which will prove that $U$ is open. Now $z\in B\Big(x,\frac{d(x,A)}{2}\Big)$ implies $d(z,x)<\frac{d(x,A)}{2}$. Then

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(z,A)&=\inf \{d(z,a):a\in A\}\\
&\geq\inf\{d(a,x)-d(z,x):a\in A\}\,[\text{As } d(a,x)\leq d(a,z)+d(z,x)]\\
&=-d(z,x)+d(x,A)>\frac{d(x,A)}{2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$

Therefore $z\in U$ and we are done.